# Mapbox-GL-JS styles that use Mapzen's vector tiles

Tags: style, vector-tiles, mapbox-gl-js, mapzen

Are there any complete, public, styles in Mapbox-GL/JS format that use [Mapzen's vector tiles](https://mapzen.com/projects/vector-tiles/)? The only one I can find is [Mapzen's own effort](http://mapzen.github.io/mapboxgl-vector-tiles/) but it doesn't look like much effort has gone into it, it's ugly, and it's very incomplete. It doesn't even have road labels.

(There are, of course, several [Mapzen styles](https://mapzen.com/products/maps/) for Tangram, but that's not what I need.)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the best example I know of https://github.com/lukasmartinelli/tilezen-gl-style

You can customize it in Maputnik, an open-source mapbox-gl style editor  http://maputnik.com/ Launch the Maputnik editor, click Open then scroll down to find the Tilezen style.

You may also want to consider using tiles from https://openmaptiles.org/ They provide a wider range of default styles for their data schema. The styles are all open-source, so you could convert them to Mapzen's schema with a bit of work.

Comment: Yes, that's the same style as the one I referred to as "Mapzen's own effort". It's better than nothing, but the colours are pretty ugly, and it only has a pretty basic range of features. No POIs, no road labels, not even any railways. I'm definitely looking at OpenMapTiles - their styles look really good. Maybe I should make a tool which can convert styles between the three schemas: Mapbox, Mapzen, OpenMapTiles. :)

Comment: Ok, I did it. https://github.com/stevage/portable-vector-style

Comment: Thats awesome! I'll try it out.

Answer (score 1):

We recently ran into this same problem so we handwrote our own mapbox styles that work with tilezen's vector tiles. They are MIT licensed and can be found [on github here](https://github.com/apollomapping/ap-tilezen-mapbox-styles)

They are much more complete than Mapzen's own effort and they work correctly with mapbox style spec v8 and the latest GL JS version (v0.44.1). Apollo Bright is a classic-ish looking style, Zen is continuation of the color scheme in Mapzen's own effort and Toner is a look a like of Stamen's Toner style.